# Android - potential bug found with default text selection CAB

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have developed an app that uses one view and loads one of two fragments in to it, depending on the orientation, i.e. portrait/landscape.

Both fragments have the same UI TextView/EditText/Button components.

When the application is in portrait mode and I press a text field for a long(ish) time, the text is selected with selection range markers and the default text selection CAB replaces the application bar.

All as expected.

However when I flip to landscape mode, although my application still works  as expected, the default text selection behavior does not work. I can still select text by long pressing a field but although the text is highlighted, there are no selection range markers and the default text selection CAB does not appear. I can do nothing with the selected text.

When I flip back to portrait mode, everything works as expected again.

I am targeting a minimum sdk of 16 and building with 19.

Is this a known bug or have I missed a step when flipping from portrait to landscape?

EDIT:

I did some further investigation in a sandbox and have found what seems to be a bug, though not sure if it is in Android or the phone itself. It also seems that this bug is triggered in both portrait and landscape modes.

I have isolated the problem in the following small app.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.foo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.example.foo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Foo</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="select_me">Select Me</string>

</resources>
```

ActivityMain.java

```
package org.example.foo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.example.foo.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.example.foo.PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_width="200dp" 
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/select_me"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

So it seems that the the layout_width and layout_height properties combined are blowing the default text selection CAB functionality.

With these parameters I can run the application and select the text, in portrait and landscape modes, with the default text selection CAB displayed as expected.

The bug is triggered if I increase either the layout_width or layout_height by one or more. Either increase will still allow me to select a word but it stops the default text selection CAB from operating, including the text selection range markers.

Further investigation shows that the bug might have some permanent effects on the current Android state, causing an internal memory leak or similar.

Consider this:

1) run the application with the properties as I have listed here and the application works as expected

2) increment either of the layout_width or layout_height properties by 1, rebuild the application and it no longer runs as expected, it now shows the bug

3) reset the adjusted property in (2), so it is now in the original state (1), rebuild the application and it still shows the bug

4) reboot the phone and the application released in (3) now works as expected

I can't think of anything else to do at this point, except report this as a bug to Android and then try to redesign my app to get around this problem.

A last thought is that this could be a hardware related bug, so perhaps someone could test this for me on a different device?

I am currently experiencing this bug on a Huawei Y300-100 phone, running Android 4.1.1

EDIT

I have reported this bug to google, issue number 68435

Answer (score 0):

I think there's more to the issue than just some dimension parameters. The below works without any issue:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout holder = new FrameLayout(this);

        int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                201,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int hieght = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                51,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,hieght);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        textView.setText("Select Me");
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        holder.addView(textView,params);

        setContentView(holder);
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not work for me, it has exactly the same results as my example. Even after changing the values to 200 and 50, I had to reboot my phone before they worked. What device did you use and what version is it running?

Comment: @Peter tested on Nexus One, and emulator.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I can do much else with this as my emulator does not do landscape mode so I am limited to testing on my phone and it definitely does not work on that.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but can never get it working. It doe snot seem to like working on opensuse and I'm not changing a distro just for one app. I never like cloud controlled dev tools. I've been told by other people they can get this test working so it seems it may be restricted to my particular phone. Guess that figures lol. I'm upgrading my droid version soon, so shall try again once I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, remove `orientation` of `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"` to avoid re-calculating offset for your cursor